# Odoo 15 Interface is not loading after installing new module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I tried to install a new module and it didn't go well. Then I am getting the below warning and the style is not loading. I tried to delete all things related to assets from database but still the problem is here. `odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(118,).raw'`

Comment: This problem you mentioned, As per my knowledge have you restored that database?
for style not loading upgrade `web` module while starting the server